# Eisenbud 2.16 - units and nilpotents

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

This should be a pretty easy problem, but I'm a dummy so I'm stuck. Here's the statement:

Let $R$ be a $\mathbb Z$-graded ring, and $M$ a graded $R$-module, and let $x \in R_k$ for some non-zero integer $k$. Then $u = 1-x$ is not a zero divisor. Show that $u$ is a unit if and only if $x$ is nilpotent.

Now I know that a similar question has been asked here many times before, so let me say that I know how to show  $u$ is not a zero divisor, and I can show that if $x$ is nilpotent, $u$ is a unit. This is easy and has been done on this site a million times. My struggle is in the converse, that is to say, if $u$ is a unit, then I want to prove that $x$ is nilpotent.

Apologies if this has also already been done on this site, but I can't seem to find the question on hand.

Comment: I suppose you don't need a graded module to state the question.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that $$(1-x)y=1$$ and let $y=\sum y_i$ be a sum of homogeneous elements $y_i$ then we have 
$$\sum y_i-xy_i=1$$
 Now we see that 
$$y_0=1$$ and that 
$$y_{i+k}=xy_i$$

Since the sum is finite, $x$ is nilpotent.

Note that if $-l$ is the smallest negative index where $y_{-l}$ is non zero then (assuming, $k$ positive by symmetry) we have
$$y_{-l}+xy_{-l}=0$$ and since these have different degrees 
$y_{-l}=0$.

Comment: This seems to only work if $R_n=0$ for negative $n$, no?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was implicitly assuming that, force of habit.

Comment: No wait it follows.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus is the argument that the sum has to be telescoping? I'm not sure I see why that's necessary, although I can see that it would be sufficient.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus nice catch!

Comment: The argument is $y_0=1$ so $y_k=x$ and $y_{2k}=x^2$ etc. Now for large values all $y_n=0$ so a power of $x$ is zero.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Ah I see now. Thanks. I was really close, I just forgot the fundamental property of the grading - $R_iR_j \subset R_{i+j}$! It was in fact, an easy question.